Is there a function to return odd values from one list and even values from another list and replace the positions each other?
another_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    
output_list = [another_list[i] if i % 2 == 0 else my_list[i] for i in range(6)]
print(output_list)

This code is perfectly working. Is there any other direct method without using for loops, like slicing functions?
I tried the above method.

Almost certainly no simpler or more readable solution than you already have.

You can:

Use slicing to get the desired values from each list
Use zip to get a an iterable of tuples containing a value from one slice and a value from the other
Use itertools.chain to flatten the iterable of tuples.

Example:
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(another_list[0::2], my_list[1::2])))
[1, 'b', 3, 'd', 5, 'f']

The more-itertools package on PyPi provides an interleave function which basically combines the zip and the from_iterable calls.
>>> from more_itertools import interleave
>>> list(interleave(another_list[0::2], my_list[1::2]))
[1, 'b', 3, 'd', 5, 'f']


The code below might help to get what you want:
 l=another_list.copy()
 l[1::2]=my_list[1::2]
 print(l)


You do know that l=another_list does not create a new list right? This will modify another_list which seems like an unexpected side effect given this code.

Thank you @Mark for mentioning that, I edited my code sample.

Will try this one as well.

If you switch the roles, you can omit 1.
